# Common 17-165 Too many positional options when parsing

Tags: vhdl, fpga, vivado

I am trying to make my BASYS 3 board (xc7a35tcpg236-1) take a 4-bit input via switches and show the respective hexadecimal character on the 7-segment display.

I, however, keep getting the following error, "[Common 17-165] Too many positional options when parsing '255/ECE255Lab5-2/ECE255Lab5-2.srcs/utils_1/imports/synth_1/Display.dcp', please type 'read_checkpoint -help' for usage info."

I am not sure how to fix this and I have not been able to find a solution, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

VHDL:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;
entity Display is
Port ( --clk : in STD_LOGIC;-- 100Mhz clock on Basys 3 FPGA board
Anode_Activate : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);-- 4 Anode signals
LED_out : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (6 downto 0);-- Cathode patterns of 7-segment display
sw : in STD_logic_vector(3 downto 0));
end Display;
architecture Behavioral of Display is
begin
process(sw)
begin
anode_activate <= "0000";
case sw is
when "0000" => LED_out <= "0000001"; -- "0"
when "0001" => LED_out <= "1001111"; -- "1"
when "0010" => LED_out <= "0010010"; -- "2"
when "0011" => LED_out <= "0000110"; -- "3"
when "0100" => LED_out <= "1001100"; -- "4"
when "0101" => LED_out <= "0100100"; -- "5"
when "0110" => LED_out <= "0100000"; -- "6"
when "0111" => LED_out <= "0001111"; -- "7"
when "1000" => LED_out <= "0000000"; -- "8"
when "1001" => LED_out <= "0000100"; -- "9"
when "1010" => LED_out <= "0000010"; -- a
when "1011" => LED_out <= "1100000"; -- b
when "1100" => LED_out <= "0110001"; -- C
when "1101" => LED_out <= "1000010"; -- d
when "1110" => LED_out <= "0110000"; -- E
when "1111" => LED_out <= "0111000"; -- F
when others => NULL;
end case;
end process;
end Behavioral;
```

XDC:

```
set_property PACKAGE_PIN W4 [get_ports {Anode_Activate[3]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN V4 [get_ports {Anode_Activate[2]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN U4 [get_ports {Anode_Activate[1]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN U2 [get_ports {Anode_Activate[0]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN W7 [get_ports {LED_out[6]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN W6 [get_ports {LED_out[5]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN U8 [get_ports {LED_out[4]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN V8 [get_ports {LED_out[3]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN U5 [get_ports {LED_out[2]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN V5 [get_ports {LED_out[1]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN U7 [get_ports {LED_out[0]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN W17 [get_ports {sw[3]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN W16 [get_ports {sw[2]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN V16 [get_ports {sw[1]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN V17 [get_ports {sw[0]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {Anode_Activate[3]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {Anode_Activate[2]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {Anode_Activate[1]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {Anode_Activate[0]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {LED_out[6]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {LED_out[5]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {LED_out[4]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {LED_out[3]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {LED_out[2]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {LED_out[1]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {LED_out[0]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {sw[3]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {sw[2]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {sw[1]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {sw[0]}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem had to do with a file being generated in the Utility folder.  I have no idea why it was there, but the bitstream generated perfectly after I deleted everything in the Utility folder.